# R: Number of a specific entry in a matrix row

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix where the entries are the numbers 0, 1, 2, or 3. I am trying to determine the number of rows in this matrix that contain the number "3" two times. Here is my code/output so far:

```
> test <-replicate(100, sample(0:3, 7, replace=T))
> test <- t(test)
> test <- subset(test, rowSums(test)==7)
> test
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    0    3    1    0    3    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    2    2    0    2
[3,]    1    0    0    2    0    3    1
[4,]    0    1    2    3    1    0    0
[5,]    1    1    1    3    1    0    0
[6,]    3    0    0    0    2    1    1
```

So for instance, row 1 contains the number "3" twice, but I want to go through the entire matrix and check each row to see if "3" occurs twice. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `test[rowSums(test == 3) == 2, ]` to check for exactly two occurrences of 3 in the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer to close this question out.

---

It seems like you want

```
test[rowSums(test == 3) == 2, ]
```

For your example data, you'll need `drop = FALSE` since there is only one row where 3 occurs exactly twice. Otherwise, R would drop the one row matrix down to a vector.

```
test[rowSums(test == 3) == 2, , drop = FALSE]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
# [1,]    0    3    1    0    3    0    0
```

To be safe, you may want to use `drop = FALSE` in the actual data as well

Comment: What do you mean you can't replicate the data? You can just copy the out put of `test`

Comment: `soread()`? Is that another crazy function written by Ananda?

Comment: Yeah, you don't use it?? It's great.